# jQuery Color Picker - retrieve saved value

Tags: jquery, colors, picker

I am implementing a color picker into a builder. 
http://colpick.com/plugin
The selected color is stored in database. Once retrieved, it does not reflect the real color on a color picker. Instead, the color picker sets the default value. Also, It does not remember the color after page reload.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is the code we use to call out the picker and save the color value:

```js
 <script>
        set_field_visibility();
        $('.picker').colpick({
            flat: true,
            layout: 'hex',
            submit: 0,
            onChange: function(a, hex, c, element, e) {
                var id = $(element).attr('id') + '_color';
                console.log(id);
                $('#' + id).val('#' + hex);
            }
        });

    </script>
```

This is what I have tried but still no luck.

```js
$('#picker').colpick({
  layout:'hex',
  submit:0,
  colorScheme:'dark',
  onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
    $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
    // Fill the text box just if the color was set using the picker, and not the colpickSetColor function.
    if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
  }
}).keyup(function(){
  $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flymen777/mtuau8od/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the stored color value in the `color` option. Like this:

`$('#picker').colpick({
    flat:true,
    layout:'hex',
    submit:0,
    color: 'fff000'
});`